# Sum values of a row after giving a numeric value to a varchar

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.3, postgresql-9.2

I have two tables, `table_a` and `table_b` as below.

Table `table_a`:

```
  a_id |columna |varchar1|varchar2|varchar3
----------------------------------
|   1  |  a     | Medium |  High  | n/a 
|   2  |  b     | Low    |  n/a   | n/a
|   3  |  c     | Medium |  Low   | High
```

In `table_a` each varchar value is given a numerical value:
*High* as 1, *Medium* as 2 and *Low* as 3.

Table `table_b`:

```
  b_id |columna_fk|average
--------------------------
|   1  |  a       |
|   1  |  b       |
|   3  |  c       |
```

How to get average values (ignoring n/a) of row and update average column in `table_b`?

For example see table below:

```
  b_id |columna_fk|average
--------------------------
|   1  |  a       | 1.5
|   1  |  b       | 3
|   3  |  c       | 2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for you answer, I made few changes and it's working for me. below is my change.

```
update b
set average = 
(case when 
((case varchar1 when 'High' then 1 when 'Medium' then 2 when 'Low' then 3 else 0 end) +
 (case varchar2 when 'High' then 1 when 'Medium' then 2 when 'Low' then 3 else 0 end) +
 (case varchar3 when 'High' then 1 when 'Medium' then 2 when 'Low' then 3 else 0 end)) <> 0 
then
((case varchar1 when 'High' then 1 when 'Medium' then 2 when 'Low' then 3 else 0 end) +
 (case varchar2 when 'High' then 1 when 'Medium' then 2 when 'Low' then 3 else 0 end) +
 (case varchar3 when 'High' then 1 when 'Medium' then 2 when 'Low' then 3 else 0 end)) 
/
((case varchar1 when 'n/a' then 0 else 1 end) +
 (case varchar2 when 'n/a' then 0 else 1 end) +
 (case varchar3 when 'n/a' then 0 else 1 end))
else null end)
from a where a.columna = b.columna_fk;
```

Answer (score 1):

One method is brute force:

```
update b
    set average = ((case varchar1 when 'High' then 1 when 'Medium' then 2 when 'Low' then 3 end) +
                   (case varchar2 when 'High' then 1 when 'Medium' then 2 when 'Low' then 3 end) +
                   (case varchar3 when 'High' then 1 when 'Medium' then 2 when 'Low' then 3 end)
                  ) /
                  nullif((case varchar1 when 'n/a' then 0 else 1 end) +
                         (case varchar2 when 'n/a' then 0 else 1 end) +
                         (case varchar3 when 'n/a' then 0 else 1 end)
                        )
    from a
    where a.columna = b.columna_fk;
```

Comment: Hi @Gordon, Thanks for your answer but I am getting a syntax error at the end of the last bracket ")"

Comment: @Taz . . . I don't see any obvious issue with the parentheses.